# Solving a Partial Differential Equation..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have encountered a PDE

$$K^2\frac{f_{KK}-f_{KKK}}{f_K}+H^2\frac{f_{HH}-f_{HHH}}{f_H}=0$$
where $f$ is homogeneous function of degree 1 in $H$ and $K$.

It is evident that $f=aH+bK$ is a solution of the above equation. But how can I solve it explicitly or can show that $f=aH+bK$ is the only solution.

I have tried to solve it by writing the PDE as
$$\frac{f_{KK}-f_{KKK}}{f_{HH}-f_{HHH}}=-\frac{H^2f_K}{K^2f_H}=\alpha\ne 0$$ and writing the $f=Kg(H/K)$ from the second equation we get a linear ODE and solving it we get $f=c(\alpha K^3-H^3)^{1/3}$. But alpha is an another function of degree 0. Putting this value in the first ratio again gives an complicated PDE. Is there any other way? Thanks for your help.